# Raw Ham Roast...How to smoke

Tags: smoking, roast, raw, ham

I was given a frozen ham roast from a friend who bought a hog.  I have a smoker and was wondering how to smoke a raw ham roast...

Comment: Have you ever used your smoker?

Answer (score 2):

Smoking a ham roast is no different than smoking a turkey or whole pork tenderloin...low and slow using the wood chips you like.....you might look at the manual that came with your smoker or cruise the internet for flavoring ideas.   How long does it take to smoke a raw ham? It should take about 15 to 20 minutes per pound to fully cook a raw ham. We like to cook the ham until it reaches 160 degrees F (which should take anywhere from 3 to 5 hours) before wrapping it in foil and cooking it for another hour or two until it reaches 190 degrees